# Active or passive voice?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence in active or passive voice?

> The document had three errors.

Comment: You might want to try googling "active voice versus passive voice" to see what you get. The [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/539/01/) site has a nice discussion of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

It is active, in the simple past.

Active in the simple present is:

> The document has three errors.

Your original has no passive counterpart because most stative verbs (verbs that describe a state of being, or condition, as opposed to an action) do not permit such a construction.

A possible passive alternative:

> Three errors were found in the document.

and

> The document was found to have had three errors.

These can be made passive because "find" is an action verb:

> He found three errors / Three errors were found [by him].

Comment: Why would you use "to have had three errors" when "to have three errors" would be sufficient?

Comment: Because of the timing. The original was in the past tense--it had three errors--which I take to mean that it no longer has the errors. If it does, I would say, "The document has been found to have three errors"--using the past perfect "has been" to express an action (the finding of the errors) that occurred at an indefinite time in the past and that still informs the present.

Comment: @surlawda "Three errors were found in the document" is not the passive counterpart of "The document had three errors". You can't change the verb to make it fit! The OP's example has NO grammatical passive counterpart.

Comment: Truer words were never spoken. I have edited my response.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it's in the active voice, and there is no passive counterpart.

*Have* is one of those verbs that only occurs in passive constructions in its dynamic sense, as in *She was happy to find there was both water and gas to be had.* But *had* in your example is used in its stative sense, hence the impossibility of * *Three errors were had by the document*.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, a passive construction needs a form of the verb *to be* plus the past participle of the main verb.

The sentence *The document had three errors* is in the active voice. It has neither of the passive voice markers.

Note however that both the active voice *The document had three errors* and a passive equivalent *Three errors were seen in the document* contain no indication of who made the errors or failed to notice them.

When this failure to name the agent is considered evasive, it is often criticized for being '*passive*', even if the statement itself is not grammatically in the passive voice. This is possibly because the commentator is extrapolating from the infamous and genuinely passive, [Mistakes were made](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mistakes_were_made), to all utterances which seek to obfuscate the perpetrator.

Professor Pullum, coauthor of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* has compiled numerous examples of supposedly passive constructions on this [Language Log](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/passives.html#passivepostlist) page. He has also written an excellent article on the topic, [Fear and Loathing of the English Passive](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/passive_loathing.pdf). Here is the abstract:

> Writing advisers have been condemning the English passive since the
>   early 20th century. I provide an informal but comprehensive syntactic
>   description of passive clauses in English, and then exhibit numerous
>   published examples of incompetent criticism in which critics reveal
>   that they cannot tell passives from actives. Some seem to confuse the
>   grammatical concept with a rhetorical one involving inadequate
>   attribution of agency or responsibility, but not all examples are thus
>   explained. The specific stylistic charges leveled against the passive
>   are entirely baseless. The evidence demonstrates an extraordinary
>   level of grammatical ignorance among educated English language
>   critics.

Comment: But not all passives need "be":  "I'll have your bags brought up by the porter" /  "It looks like your bags got brought up by the porter". Both genuine passive clauses without "be".

Comment: @BillJ. You are right to point out that passive constructions can also be formed with the causative verbs _get_ and _have_: e.g. _to get or have something done_. There is also  the get-passive in constructions such as: _She got run over by a bus_.

Answer (score 0):

It's active, but it does have a passive-like relationship to "Three errors are in this document".  As with a real passive, a noun phrase, "this document", that starts out within the verb phrase is made into a new subject, and the original subject, "three errors", is moved down inside the new verb phrase.

A true passive of "Three errors are in this document" if it were possible, would be *"This document is been in by three errors."

Comment: The passive would be the impossible "Three errors were had by the document". Changing the verb proves nothing. It has no passive counterpart; simple as that.

Comment: @BillJ, I think you didn't read very carefully the original question or what I wrote.

Comment: @ Greg Lee I did read it carefully and I replied to it.